# SSIS 2012 Control flow pauses after Data flow task during parallel execution

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing, freeze

I have an ETL for loading few tables in full refresh mode/truncate load. There is some metadata to keep track of which all tables are loaded and which all are pending. Figure below explains it better..
[image]

The problem is that, although the tables are designed to load in parallel, the Update Metadata step waits for other Data flow tasks to complete (which are in other parallel threads of execution). Once all the data flows complete the Update steps are executed in one shot. I am not sure what is happening behind the scene and why the steps are not executed right after the data flow task. Please respond if you have any clues...

Answer (score 0):

This has bee already explained here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis.aspx

Comment: The link does not appear to answer the OP's question.